# codaslider not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, jquery-plugins

Hi all a bit of a noobie jquery problem with codaslider I'm afriad.

I am trying to add codaslider to a page that I am working on however, even after following the examples at http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/#1 I am getting errors trying to display the slider.

I am getting in Firebug the following error:

```
$("#coda-slider-1").codaSlider is not a function
http://localhost/js/ui/landingpage_ui.js
Line 10
```

This javascript code is done in a onload command when the document loads:

```
function load(){

    $().ready(function() {
        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
            dynamicArrows: false,
            dynamicTabs: false
        });
    });

}
```

The javascript is all being handles by a Zend Framework view so the actual html/php document looks like this:

```
<?php
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js', 'text/javascript');
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', 'text/javascript');
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl() . '/css/coda-slider-2.0.css');
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl() . '/css/reset.css');

$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/ui/landingpage_ui.js', 'text/javascript');

$this->layout()->bodyScripts = "onload='load()'";

?>


<div class="coda-slider-wrapper">
    <div id="coda-nav-left-1" class="coda-nav-left"><a href="#" title="Slide left">&#171;</a></div>
       <div id="coda-nav-1" class="coda-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="tab1"><a href="#1">Panel 1</a></li>
               <li class="tab2"><a href="#2">Panel 2</a></li>
               <li class="tab3"><a href="#3">Panel 3</a></li>
               <li class="tab4"><a href="#4">Panel 4</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="coda-nav-right-1" class="coda-nav-right"><a href="#" title="Slide right">&#187;</a></div>
    <div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">
        <div class="panel">

            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>

                <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
                <p>Cras luctus fringilla odio vel hendrerit. Cras pulvinar auctor sollicitudin. Sed lacus quam, sodales sit amet feugiat sit amet, viverra nec augue. Sed enim ipsum, malesuada quis blandit vel, posuere eget erat. Sed a arcu justo. Integer ultricies, nunc at lobortis facilisis, ligula lacus vestibulum quam, id tincidunt sapien arcu in velit. Vestibulum consequat augue et turpis condimentum mollis sed vitae metus. Morbi leo libero, tincidunt lobortis fermentum eget, rhoncus vel sem. Morbi varius viverra velit vel tempus. Morbi enim turpis, facilisis vel volutpat at, condimentum quis erat. Morbi auctor rutrum libero sed placerat. Etiam ipsum velit, eleifend in vehicula eu, tristique a ipsum. Donec vitae quam vel diam iaculis bibendum eget ut diam. Fusce quis interdum diam. Ut urna justo, dapibus a tempus sit amet, bibendum at lectus. Sed venenatis molestie commodo.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
                <p>Nulla ultricies ornare erat, a rutrum lacus varius nec. Pellentesque vehicula lobortis dignissim. Ut scelerisque auctor eros sed porttitor. Nullam pulvinar ultrices malesuada. Quisque lobortis bibendum nisi et condimentum. Mauris quis erat vel dui lobortis dignissim.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- .coda-slider -->
</div><!-- .coda-slider-wrapper -->
```

I am using version 2.0 of the codaslider library and 1.4.4 of jQuery main library.

Any reason why this is causing the script not to load and execute?  When I look at the source of the page generated everything seems to be there and loaded.

Many thanks.

Grant

Comment: Could you please post the `<script>` tags that are rendered instead of the PHP? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `codaSlider` plugin is based on `easing` plugin, you need to include `easing` first. So just try changing the order:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', 'text/javascript');
$this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js', 'text/javascript');
```

And don't forget to include `jquery` in the first place, so I'd suggest using `prependFile()` for `jquery` at all times:

```
$this->headScript()->prependFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js', 'text/javascript');
```